# "BIOS update requires USB to be enabled" workaround?

Tags: centos, bios

I'm trying to update BIOS on one my machines.  The system was configured to with USB disabled, and I'm not allowed to change that now.

So when I run the BIN file on my CentOS 7 machine:

```
[acoder@box acoder]# ./BIOS_7V25P_LN_2.9.1.BIN 
Collecting inventory...

Running validation...

PowerEdge R530/R430/T430 BIOS

The version of this Update Package is newer than the currently installed version.
Software application name: BIOS
Package version: 2.9.1
Installed version: 2.3.4



Continue? Y/N:y
Executing update...
WARNING: DO NOT STOP THIS PROCESS OR INSTALL OTHER PRODUCTS WHILE UPDATE IS IN PROGRESS.
THESE ACTIONS MAY CAUSE YOUR SYSTEM TO BECOME UNSTABLE!
.......
USB is not enabled. Please enable USB and try update again
```

It fails because USB is not enabled.

Is there a workaround for this or are system admins required to weaken security temporarily, just to install the BIOS updates?

Comment: This is a question you should be asking your Dell support contact, not random people on the Internet. You might also want to talk with whoever defines your security regime, to determine the proper procedure for updating the BIOS. It might include extra steps like unplugging the system from all non-essential devices for the upgrade, and/or having another competent person verify and sign off your work, and/or documenting how you've verified the authenticity of the BIOS upgrade file.